# Maximum Likelihood Estimation for a Unknown Distribution

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood

I am trying to find the MLE for an Unknown distribution. I have most of the steps but I am confused on how to simplify the $\prod$ of the denominator.

The given function is $f(x;\beta) = \frac{\beta}{(1+x)^{\beta+1}}$.
To find the MLE we first write this as $$f(x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots,x_n;\beta) = \prod_{i=1}^n\Big(\frac{\beta}{(1+x)^{\beta+1}}\Big)$$ which simplifies to

$$f(x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots,x_n;\beta) = \Big(\frac{\beta^n}{(1+x_1)^{\beta+1}\cdot(1+x_2)^{\beta+1}\cdot(1+x_3)^{\beta+1}\cdots(1+x_n)^{\beta+1}}\Big)$$
Here I am having trouble simplifying the denominator into easier to a more approachable form.

I tried to continue by taking the log which equals

$$L(\beta) = n\log(\beta)-(\beta+1)(\log((1+x_1)\cdot(1+x_2)\cdot(1+x_3)\cdots(1+x_n)))$$

However I am stuck unable to simplify here too since I can't just sum the values inside the log. How do I simplify this problem so I can solve it?

EDIT: I just realized that every value in the second log will be a constant, does this mean I can proceed with the derivative since the log will go to 0 regardless.

EDIT #2: Since the derivative of a sum is the sum of each i's derivative does that mean $\frac{L}{L(\beta)} = \frac{n}{\beta} - \frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i+1)}$

Comment: The log of the product is the sum of the logs.  You should end up with $n \log (\beta )-(\beta +1) \sum _{i=1}^n \log (x_i+1)$.

Comment: I just realized that yeah, but then when you take the derivative wouldn't it just be
d(L($\beta$)) = $\frac{n}{\beta}$ since the derivative of $(\beta + 1)*\sum(log)) = 1$

Comment: You must mention the possible values that $x$ and $\beta$ can take. This is supposed to be a [Beta distribution of second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_prime_distribution) with parameter $(1,\beta)$, so that $x>0$ and $\beta>0$.

Comment: And you need to be careful with your algebra and differentiation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copy JimB's solution while turning it into a complete answer. Your likelihood function is given by
$$
L(\beta; x_1, \dots, x_n) = \prod_{i=1}^n \left[ \frac{\beta}{(1+x_i)^{\beta+1}}\right] = \beta^n \prod_{i=1}^n \left[\frac{1}{(1+x_i)^{\beta+1}}\right].
$$
The loglikelihood is given as the natural logarith of the likelihood $l(\beta; x_1, \dots, x_n) = \ln L(\beta, x_1, \dots, x_n)$. Remember now that $\ln (a b) = \ln a + \ln b$, $\ln (a^n) = n \ln a$ and that $\ln [1/a] = -\ln a$.
$$
\begin{align}
l(\beta; x_1, \dots, x_n) &= n \ln \beta + \sum_{i=1}^n \ln \left[\frac{1}{(1+x_i)^{\beta+1}}\right] \\
& = n\ln \beta + \sum_{i=1}^n - \ln [(1+x_i)^{\beta + 1}] \\
& = n\ln \beta + \sum_{i=1}^n - (\beta + 1)\ln [1+x_i]
\end{align}
$$
When finding the MLE we want to maximize $L$ and because the $\ln$ is a monotone transform the maximum of $l$ will be the maximum of $L$. We thus derivate wrt to $\beta$
$$
\frac{\partial l}{\partial \beta}(\beta; x_1, \dots, x_n) = \frac{n}{\beta} - \sum_{i=1}^n \ln [1+x_i]
$$
and find the critical points for which $\frac{\partial l}{\partial \beta} = 0$, 
$$
\frac{n}{\beta} - \sum_{i=1}^n \ln [1+x_i] = 0 \, \Longrightarrow \, \hat{\beta}_\text{MLE} = \frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^n \ln [1+x_i]}
$$
Now here we can check that $\hat{\beta}_\text{MLE}$ gives the max and not the min of the loglikelihood as
$$
\frac{\partial^2 l}{\partial \beta^2} = -\frac{n}{\beta^2} < 0 \quad \forall \beta
$$
the double derivative is negative.

Comment: Thanks for answering. When I was solving it, I left the $\beta^n$ as the numerator when I took the log and I resulted in a different answer, can you help me figure out where I went wrong. $$Log(f(x_1,x_2,x_3...x_n;\beta)) = Log\Big( \Big(\frac{\beta^n}{(1+x_1)^{\beta+1}\cdot(1+x_2)^{\beta+1}\cdot(1+x_3)^{\beta+1}\cdot...\cdot(1+x_n)^{\beta+1}}\Big) \Big) $$ which led to this $$L(\beta) = nLog(\beta) - (\beta + 1)((\sum_{i=1}^n Log(x_i + 1))) $$ which led to this $$\frac{L}{L(\beta)} = \frac{n}{\beta} - \frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i+1)} $$ resulting in $$ n \cdot \sum_{i=1}^n(x_i+1) = \hat{\beta}$$

Comment: The fault happens when you derive
$$
-(\beta + 1)(\sum_{i=1}^n(\ln (x_i+1))
$$
which is 
$$
\frac{\partial }{\partial \beta} [ -(\beta + 1)(\sum_{i=1}^n(\ln (x_i+1))] = - \sum_{i=1}^n(\ln (x_i+1))
$$
and not
$$
\frac{\partial }{\partial \beta} [ -(\beta + 1)(\sum_{i=1}^n(\ln (x_i+1))] \neq - \frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^n(\ln (x_i+1))}
$$

Comment: Ah I see thank you for clarifying, is it possible for you show the steps of the derivation?

Comment: Actually, I get it. The partial derivative would just be the derivative of the outside term $-(\beta+1)$ times the sum, which is negative 1 times the sum. Thanks again!

Comment: Would you mind accepting the answer please?

Comment: Of course, thank you again!

Comment: Why don't you write $\dfrac{\beta^n}{X^\beta}$ where $X=(1+x_1)\cdots(1+x_n)$ and just work with $\dfrac{\beta^n}{X^\beta}$ until the end, when you can recall what $X$ is?

Comment: @Michael: That's definitely a good trick to simplifying the derivation procedure!